# Powershell Merge XML Data into CSV

Tags: powershell

i'm trying to merge some data gathered from the same XML file. If I export them like this i obtain a file which cannot be used to import data. Here's the code:

```
[xml]$inputFile = Get-Content "$savepath\config.xml"
$inputFile.appcmd.APPPOOL | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" | Set-Content "$savepath\config.csv" -Encoding UTF8
$inputFile.appcmd.APPPOOL.add.recycling | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" | Add-Content "$savepath\config.csv" -Encoding UTF8
$inputFile.appcmd.APPPOOL.add.recycling.Childnodes | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" | Add-Content "$savepath\config.csv" -Encoding UTF8
$inputFile.appcmd.APPPOOL.add.cpu | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" | Add-Content "$savepath\config.csv" -Encoding UTF8
$inputFile.appcmd.APPPOOL.add.failure | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" | Add-Content "$savepath\config.csv" -Encoding UTF8
$inputFile.appcmd.APPPOOL.add.processmodel | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" | Add-Content "$savepath\config.csv" -Encoding UTF8
```

All the new data should be imported like a new column.
Here's the out file:

```
"APPPOOL.NAME";"PipelineMode";"RuntimeVersion";"state";"add"
"DefaultAppPool";"Classic";"v4.0";"Started";"System.Xml.XmlElement"
"logEventOnRecycle";"periodicRestart"
"Time, Requests, Schedule, Memory, IsapiUnhealthy, OnDemand, ConfigChange";"System.Xml.XmlElement"
"privateMemory";"requests";"time";"schedule"
"5000";"1";"1.05:01:00";""
"limit";"smpAffinitized";"numaNodeAssignment"
"50000";"true";"MostAvailableMemory"
"orphanWorkerProcess";"rapidFailProtectionInterval";"rapidFailProtectionMaxCrashes";"autoShutdownExe"
"true";"00:01:00";"6";"1"
"maxProcesses";"pingInterval"
"2";"00:00:31"
```

As you can see, for example, the rows (2-3) (4-5) (6-7)... should be next to the first two and so on.
Here's the content of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<appcmd>

    <APPPOOL APPPOOL.NAME="DefaultAppPool" PipelineMode="Classic" RuntimeVersion="v4.0" state="Started">

        <add name="DefaultAppPool" enable32BitAppOnWin64="true" managedPipelineMode="Classic">

            <processModel maxProcesses="2" pingInterval="00:00:31" />

            <recycling logEventOnRecycle="Time, Requests, Schedule, Memory, IsapiUnhealthy, OnDemand, ConfigChange">

                <periodicRestart privateMemory="5000" requests="1" time="1.05:01:00">

                    <schedule>

                    </schedule>

                </periodicRestart>

            </recycling>

            <failure orphanWorkerProcess="true" rapidFailProtectionInterval="00:01:00" rapidFailProtectionMaxCrashes="6" autoShutdownExe="1" />

            <cpu limit="50000" smpAffinitized="true" numaNodeAssignment="MostAvailableMemory" />

            <environmentVariables>

            </environmentVariables>

        </add>

    </APPPOOL>

</appcmd>
```

Comment: Can you post the config.xml content?

Comment: Edit: Added XML File

Comment: You can't convert a XML to a csv just like that. You need to flatten your data and determine what you want to export. You should use `| ConvertTo-CSV` on the collection of objects to export rather then on each thing like you do... Your current csv example is very much invalid.